How to check if last item on ModalRoute is a PopupMenuButton in flutter?
How to check if last widget on stack is PopupMenuButton to pop:
I want to only pop if its a PopupMenu.
I use :
if (previousRoute is "PleaseFillHere") {
      context.pop();
    }


Can anyone help? It seems not hard but I cant find a solution online.

you want to pop from PopupMenuButton and also the page that is present right?

@Hitesh Kinda want to pop only the PoupMenuButton.

actually if tap any where out side popupmenu it will pop, so can you please elaborate the question.

I found a solution. The navigation Rail is in top of the PopupMenu in route stack ,so if you tap it it will navigate and the menu wouldnt close so I put the Poupmenu "useRootNavigator: true", to make the The Navigationrail not clickable.
